# How many of "tags" and "predicted_dependencies" in the dependency parsing (allennlp.predictors.predictor)?

Tags: allennlp, dependency-parsing

I am using "allennlp.predictors.predictor" to extract the information of dependency parsing for sentences. May I know how many numbers of "tags" and "predicted_dependencies" are in the dependency parsing? I can not find the exactly number of "tags" and "predicted_dependencies". Is there any reference?

Comment: Which model are you using exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.